# MongoDB document deleted locally but not on MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mlab

This Mongoose delete method seems to work Ok locally with HttpRequester

```
router.delete('/', (req, res) => {
    Book.findOneAndRemove({ title: req.body.title })
      .then(() => res.json({ 'book deleted': 'success' }))
      .catch(err => console.log('Couldn\'t delete book:', err));
  }
);
```

but the MongoLab collection still shows the document. How to get it deleted remotely too? `findOneAndDelete()` didn't make a difference.
The complete repo is on https://github.com/ElAnonimo/booklist

Comment: are you sure your delete request is being processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findOneAndRemove` had issues earlier.

`findByIdAndRemove` works fine.

```
router.delete('/', (req, res) => {
    Book.findOne({ title: req.body.title })
      .then((doc) => if(doc)return Book.findByIdAndRemove(doc._id))
      .then(() => res.json({ 'book deleted': 'success' }))
      .catch(err => console.log('Couldn\'t delete book:', err));
  }
);
```

or even better you can do as follows

```
router.delete('/', (req, res) => {
    Book.deleteOne({ title: req.body.title })
      .then(() => res.json({ 'book deleted': 'success' }))
      .catch(err => console.log('Couldn\'t delete book:', err));
  }
);
```

Comment: The former returns `Cannot read property '_id' of null` once you remove `return` and rewrite the piece. The latter doesn't remove the remote document. The complete repo is on https://github.com/ElAnonimo/booklist

Comment: Can you explain me what you mean by 'remote document' ?

Comment: The book stored on MongoLab.

Comment: I use mlab all the time. deleteOne works fine.  Have you entered the url correctly and user mLab user is correct ?

Comment: You can check in the repo should you feel like so. I believe the uri was correct I added a book with it.

Comment: @ElAnonimo  I've delete successfully with `deleteOne`. You can check your database on mLab. I've generated some book and delete them

Answer (score 1):

Have you change your URI connection to MongoDB on mLab?. I think you've changed it yet.

Please sure use `mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds12xxxx.mlab.com:27342/[database_name]`, not locally `'mongodb://localhost/[database_name]'`

If you've changed it, please use `deleteOne` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteOne, it's working well.

Comment: The URI used was the correct one for the remote MongoLab database.

Comment: @ElAnonimo I've generated some book on your database mLab from your github https://github.com/ElAnonimo/booklist and `deleteOne` is working when I deleted your book 3 successfully

Comment: I delete book 3, sorry, now I'll delete book 4

Comment: I've just delete book 4

Comment: Seems so. Let me try again.

Comment: `// delete book
router.delete('/', (req, res) => {
    Book.deleteOne({ title: req.body.title })
      .then(() => res.json({ 'book deleted': 'success' }))
      .catch(err => console.log('Couldn\'t delete book:', err));
  }
);` doesn't delete for me. I run HttpRequester with `{"title": "book6"}` for Content nothing gets deleted. But I'll leave the code you guys suggested.

Comment: You should `console.log(req.body.title)`, I think your request with method DELETE having a problem with `body`. I've tried by Postman https://www.getpostman.com/ to call API delete and it's working. Because `deleteOne()` won't find in your database if exist record, so your API always sends message success. Maybe help you